# How to checking whether temperatures for SSD and HDD are correct. 22.04

Tags: ssd, 22.04, overheating, temperature

Is there a way to check whether the temperature taken from the Disks and Psensor GUI are correct? Reason I'm asking is because regardless whether it's cold boot or after running for a couple of hours, the SSD always shows 74 degrees. The idling HDD cold boot at 29 degree and goes to 34+-; which I'm not sure whether it's normal. Top screenshot is from Psensor and bottom is from Disks (right after cold boot):

[image]
[image]

Kindly advise.

Comment: HDD temps are normal, actually great, and perfectly healthy. The SSD temp, if correct, is on the worrying zone but if it boots and stays at the same value then its sensor isn't working. Unless you notice actual problems there's nothing to worry about.

Comment: Seems obvious, but since you've asked, ...just measure is with a thermometer.